# Handling Images in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

How to add single image in drupal in a block region and how to manage slideshow in drupal 7.
I am newbie in drupal Please give me step by step explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple image by just including it in code `<img src="<url>">` and selecting the FULL HTML Filter

There are tonnes of options for slide shows, see the list here:
http://drupal.org/node/418616

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need to add image from drupal admin.i have region just above fotter like triptych_first, triptych_middle and triptych_last.I want to add single image in these regions through admin.

Comment: To add to the "region", modify the theme's css or some template file eg. page.tpl.php

Comment: I am not asking to add regions.I have already create regions now i want to add image in that region.How can i do this?

Comment: thats exactly what I said, edit the css file and add something like  `.region-name{background-image:ur(/sites/default/mytheme/images/myimage.png)}` or in the template file, in the region code add `<img src="/sites/default/files/image.png">`

Comment: thanx but if i want to change that image i have to edit this code every time.i need to do this through admin so no need to change code when i change the image.

Comment: I found the solution using this module http://drupalmodules.org/module/image-block

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image in the block region by creating a custom block and use a PHP code 
sites/default/files/image-name.jpg">

For creating a slideshow in drupal 7, you can use view slideshow cs module.

For making a slideshow in drupal you have to follow few steps :

- Create a content type for slideshow
- create view and use a slideshow in the setting
- add the images using content type
- enjoy the slideshow